# Cairo dock on other workspaces

Tags: workspaces, cairo-dock

The Cairo-Dock is showing only on the first workspace. How can I enable it in other worksapces?

(FYI I use Lubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you're switching between workspaces or desktops? It's different and if you're using Compiz, you should only use one desktop with several workspaces. (you can change these settings by opening the Compiz Config Settings Manager in the General section

[image]

set number of Desktops to 1.

Comment: I did what you said, and I added workspace in workspace swithcer of cairo-dock, but it nothing changed.

Comment: checkout [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~cairo-dock-team/+archive/weekly) and install a stable version perhaps. I'll get back to you soon.